# Select * wont print anything in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

i made a php script as below ran it and ouput is Record Added to Table

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test_db";
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "INSERT INTO name (FirstName) VALUES ('bill')";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

mysql_close($db_handle);

print "Records added to the database";
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}

?>
```

now to see the content of the table i did

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test_db";
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "Select * from name";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

print "$result";
mysql_close($db_handle);

print "Records added to the database";
}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}

?>
```

But the output is Resource id #3Records added to the database, while i want to see the contents of the table

Comment: If you have access to something like PHPMyAdmin try to see if your added data is exist on DB? Also if you are looking for a easy class to connect with mysql have a look at this guide http://www.electronicspub.com/article/19/PHP-MySQL-Connection-class.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value of mysql_query can not be sent to the output like you try.

mysql_query returns a resultset, to be used with http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_row for example.

Example:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

Comment: use my_sql fetch and output is blank, is there any way i can see the table

Comment: i just want to be sure records are being added

Answer (score 1):

`$result` contains the return value from `mysql_query` which is a `resource` *( http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)*

use `mysql_fetch_assoc($result)` or `mysql_fetch_array($result)` or ... to have the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
    printf("Result: %s", $row[0]);  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mysql_query()` will return a resultset object which you have to read in a loop to get its rows:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array()) {
   echo htmlspecialchars($row['column1']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select from the database try this:

```
<?PHP

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "test_db";
$server = "127.0.0.1";
$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if ($db_found) {

$SQL = "Select * from name";
$result = mysql_query($SQL);

 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
  print $row[0]." Record is selected";
 }
mysql_close($db_handle);


}
else {
print "Database NOT Found ";
mysql_close($db_handle);
}

?>
```